# Adding a function to $resource prototype

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I'm trying to add a view function to an Angular $resource. I add it to the $resource via prototype but for some reason the 'this' reference in the prototype function is incorrect so all of the properties are undefined. Strangely though in console.log the this seems to have all the properties it would need to return correctly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YsTlAztjEKjn3piQAem2?p=preview

```
app.factory("Now", function($resource) {

  var Now = $resource("http://date.jsontest.com/");

  Now.prototype.$dateTime = function() {
    console.log("2", this); // this has date and time properties, good
    return this.date + " " + this.time;
  };

  return Now;
});

app.controller("TestController", function(Now) {
  var now = new Now();
  now.$get();
  console.log("1", now); // prototype has the $dateTime function!
  console.log("3", now.$dateTime()); // but it returns undefined, bad
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your error is that your calling $dateTime before the resource returns with the data.

See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQ4p7aH4UDC73GQ3x8bY?p=preview)

The only reason the answer above me appears to work is it is being interpolated, and when the resource finally returns, the datetime function is called AGAIN.  But if you were to leave the code the same, it would still fail

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to use the properties of `this` while the model is still being fetched from the server which is resulting in those properties being undefined when you ask for them.  You need to use the promise methods that are available on the object returned from `$get` in order to guarantee that the request has finished.

This

`now.$get();`

Should become this

`now.$get().then(function() {
  console.log("1", now);
  console.log("3", now.$dateTime());
});`

Comment: Nice work and the correct answer. Have to give it to Erik Donohoo though because he got it first.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in using `.factory`. It expects an object to be returned, but $resource is a function. Change it to `.service` and it will work

```
app.service("now", function($resource) {
```

complete code: http://plnkr.co/edit/n31MMNTlKV3i04HdXUms?p=catalogue

```
var app = angular.module("test", ["ngResource"]);

app.service("now", function($resource) {

  var now = $resource("http://date.jsontest.com/");

  now.prototype.dateTime = function() {
    return this.date + " " + this.time;
  };

  return now;
});

app.controller("TestController", function($scope, now) {
  $scope.now = now.get();
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what is returned by a factory. In fact using `.service` like you do has the same effect and doesn't make sense, as `.service` is meant for constructor functions.